# Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Binary to type Text. M/Power Query in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, binary, expression, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

`   let
// Define the API endpoint URL
apiUrl = "https://collibra.com/rest/2.0/outputModule/export/csv?validationEnabled=false&headerRow=true",

```
// Define the username and password for Basic Authentication
username = "username",
password = "password",

// Create a Base64-encoded string for the credentials
base64Credentials = Text.ToBinary(Text.Combine({username, ":", password}, "")),
authHeader = "Basic " & Binary.ToText(Binary.FromText(base64Credentials, BinaryEncoding.Base64)),

// Define the request headers
headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json", #"Authorization"=authHeader],`
```

I wanted to call a post api which takes json body as input in powerBi power query.
I'm getting expression error(Binary to text conversion error) when trying to achieve the post request (which uses basic authentication) in power query. Is there any other way to authenticate basic auth in Power Query?

I tried, changing binary.toText with text.fromBinary, and tried to remove the whole binary conversion functions. Both are giving me "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided."